# Remove whitespaces from string in one jsp page and get again that space in another jsp page

Tags: java, string

I have a jsp page in which their is a string that have some spaces between them. 
On that jsp page i remove that space by replaceAll() method than when i pass these string on another jsp page, then i want that space again for checking with it a properties file that have same string with all spaces.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

On your first jsp page, use a new variable to store your string and do a replaceAll on that string. Then use the same local variable on your first jsp. While passing the parameters to another jsp, use the original string.

If you do a replaceAll on the original string, there's no way you can recover the value on another jsp.

Comment: I understand but actually i want to do this -
http://localhost:8080/wap/live.jsp?v=Aaj%20Tak
to
http://localhost:8080/wap/live.jsp?v=AajTak
but here now i want that i can get "Aaj Tak" again not AajTak

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea. Instead I suggest, if you don't like how `%20` looks, just change it to `_` and then change it back again in the other jsp.

Comment: So there is no way...so then i will use %20 to _ .